# Execute user flow on Azure B2C with Angular SPA MSAL library

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup a Azure B2C for experimenting, and have created a signupandsign as a user flow.

I've followed the github samples on how to use the MSAL library from Angular 2+ and have as a result got this format:

```
export const protectedResourceMap: [string, string[]][] = [
  ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']],
];

function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.clientId,
      authority: environment.authority,
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
    cache: {
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // set to true for IE 11
    },
  };
}

function MSALAngularConfigFactory(): MsalAngularConfiguration {
  return {
    popUp: false,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  clientId: '22ccxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/bc5xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/',
  redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
};
```

But all it does it take to sign in page, doesn't give me any options for sign up.
How do i trigger the signupandsign user flow from my Angular SPA?

Comment: Which samples have you looked at? Do you have a link?

Comment: Here is the main one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/

Comment: The documentation in some cases is horrific to say the least

Comment: Please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa) for b2c with policy. The authority URL needs to be like `https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_susi` which refers the policy

Comment: Following the tutorial it refers to using Implicit and not PKCE. It also contradicts the microsofts own announcement to use MSAL 2+ which advises to use SPA setting (PKCE). MSAL 2+ link about PKCE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-20-with-auth-code-flow

Comment: if you see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-20-with-auth-code-flow) there is an important note saying "MSAL.js 2.0 does not currently support Azure AD B2C for use with the PKCE authorization code flow. At this time, Azure AD B2C recommends using the implicit flow as described in Tutorial: Register an application." Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample which you are referring helps you to Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from an Angular single-page application.

In the document you can see below note which points you to the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular)

```
Note: A more detailed tutorial covering this sample can be found here.
```

Please refer the [Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa) for B2C Angular SPA.

Comment: As per my comment this follows the Implicit method which is not fit for purpose for SPA applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-20-with-auth-code-flow

Comment: Raghavendra do you know if MSAL PKCE has been rectified for use by Angular apps, or do we still have to use the implicit flow? If so do you have any links to how it should be setup?